# Android, special drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I need to create a drawable with some special behavior on resizing:

[image: Pejman Chatrrooz]

is that even possible ? and I don't want to use nine-patch and I've tried this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <size android:width="10dp" />
      <solid android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:left="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <size android:width="10dp" />
      <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: does it have to be all xml based?

Comment: Yes @pskink I have to :'(

Comment: no pngs at all? it could be difficult...

Comment: No @pskink it's really important to be `xml`

Comment: ok i see, but what about code based solution: class MySuperDrawable extends Drawable { ....?

Comment: my i know why you cannot do it in java code?

Comment: that's a good solution but i want to use it for indeterminate animation of my custom progress bar, I want to stay away from writing codes for layout in java, This is really important for me to JUST use xml.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42521/discussion-between-omid-and-pskink)

Comment: in java you just implement a custom Drawable, nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think you can do it in pure xml, so try this custom Drawable:

```
public class StripDrawable extends Drawable {

    private static final int FIRST_COLOR = 0xff3a3a3a;
    private static final int SECOND_COLOR = 0xff04dfff;
    private static final float STRIP_WIDTH = 10;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mWidth;

    public StripDrawable(Context ctx) {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            STRIP_WIDTH,
            ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect b = getBounds();
        float w = b.left;
        while (w < b.right) {
            mPaint.setColor(FIRST_COLOR);
            canvas.drawRect(w, b.top, w + mWidth, b.bottom, mPaint);
            w += mWidth;
            mPaint.setColor(SECOND_COLOR);
            canvas.drawRect(w, b.top, w + mWidth, b.bottom, mPaint);
            w += mWidth;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```